# Using div() on multivariate polynomials in Sympy: incorrect remainder?

Tags: python, sympy, division, polynomials, groebner-basis

I want to compute remainders in Python for multivariate polynomials and I found that div() from sympy should do the trick (I also need sympy for Gröbner computations). But the problem I keep finding is that it seems that div() only checks the leading term for division because

```
q, r = div(x**2 + y, 2*x)
```

gives `r=y`, while

```
q, r = div(x**2 + y, 2*y)
```

gives `r=x**2+y`.

I want to do things like Ideal Membership, hence finding the remainder of some polynomial f on division by G={g_1,...,g_s}, where by above I now cannot rely upon div().

Whilst working with Sage I don't get this problem (using (x^2+y)%y gives x^2), but I'm more familier with Python and prefer to do this via Python.

Can someone please tell me if I'm doing something wrong? Or does someone know a better function to use for remainders?

Comment: There are Groebner basis methods, such as `groebner([g]).reduce(f)` and `groebner([g]).contains(f)`, but I couldn't make them work on your example.

Comment: Thank you for your very quick respond. I feel bad for not answering earlier, but I finally found a good alternative: 

reduced(x^2+y,[2*y]) gives the desired ([1/2], x^2)

Comment: Post it as an answer, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good alternative: `reduced(x**2+y, [2*y])` gives the desired ([1/2], x^2).